# XLS download in node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, express

I have implemented the below sample code for creating excel file in node.js.

What is exactly want is this automatically created file to be downloadable when user clicks on a download button.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("file.xls");

var header="Sl No"+"\t"+" Age"+"\t"+"Name"+"\n";
var row1 = "0"+"\t"+" 21"+"\t"+"Rob"+"\n";
var row2 = "1"+"\t"+" 22"+"\t"+"bob"+"\n";

writeStream.write(header);
writeStream.write(row1);
writeStream.write(row2);

writeStream.close();
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The file was automatically saved in the app path. Then I setted the headers and piped it with response

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.xls');
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');

var file = __dirname + '/file.xls';
var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
filestream.pipe(res);
```

And in the code I had to use a single string and concatenate them instead of seperate header and row variable. i.e

```
var testToWrite="Sl No"+"\t"+" Age"+"\t"+"Name"+"\n"+"0"+"\t"+" 21"+"\t"+"Rob"+"\n"+"1"+"\t"+" 22"+"\t"+"bob"+"\n";
```